# Problema al importar Bootstrap js con npm

Tags: javascript, bootstrap, vscode

Instalé Bootstrap v5 (beta) vía npm,  es mi primera vez que lo uso.
tengo los archivos de Bootstrap guardados en Node_Modules y ya logré importar los archivos sass correspondientes para que funcione bootstrap. Al menos los de SASS

tengo problemas al importar las herramientas, los archivos js, a mi archivo principal de JS.

Al correr mi pagina los estilos funcionan bien, pero el JS no y no me marca ni un error.

Quisiera saber cuál  es la forma correcta de importar los archivos JS al principal (main.js).

lo tengo  de la siguiente forma:

Mi html:

```
<script src="Js/js_main.js" type="module"></script>
```

Mi código  es el  siguiente (js):

import * as bootstrap from '../node_modules/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js';

console.log(bootstrap);

Gracias :D

Comment: no entiendo tu pregunta yo uso boostrap instalado con npm simplemente importandolo en el main de mi applicacion import 'bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css';

Comment: eso hago peero nunca me deja hacer  huzo  de su contenido

Comment: Con tener instalado bootstrap con npm debería ser suficiente , y despues importandolo en el main de tu aplicación. Posteriormente solo tienes que acudir a la documentacion de bootstrap e importar el codigo necesario para el componente que quieras usar